# Edit Document Stored in ECM from remote application

Tags: sharepoint, content-management-system, ecm

We are planning to allow the users to attach documents from our HTML app. The Documents are stored in Enterprise Content Management system (ECM). The ECM system could be different for each client. The Question i have is, how do i edit the documents stored from an ECM system online from our app. The document attached would just show as a link. The document can be opened in a native software like Word, Excel but saving the document should directly save it to the ECM System. I don't want the user to download, change and upload again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're storing your documents with ECM. If you've set up ECM to store documents internally in the ECM database, then you're probably out of luck, as external access to the ECM database could be breaking copyright etc. Find out first. If they are stored on disc, then simply link your application to the document file in your "database" of folders. And yes, giving outside ECM access to those documents, you'll need your client program, to save the document externally into another location. I would therefore lock down the folder(s) that have your documents to specific users, admin, etc but never to ECM, as it needs full access. ie: Force Windows to ask the user to save the file into another location.